# Using php Doctrine, is there any way to do a relationship through two columns with different collations?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

I want to do a relationship between two columns that have two different collations. I made the relationship and when I do a join in query builder it returns:

> "Cannot resolve the collation conflict"

I already found out that I can do something to join the tables:

```
$this->_em->createQueryBuilder()...
->leftJoin(SomeEntity::class, 'entity2', Join::WITH, 
'collate(entity1.login, database_default) = collate(entity2.login, 
database_default)')...
```

where `collate()` is a custom function.

But I really need to do this? There is no way that doctrine just automatically put the word "`COLLATE`" in the query?

Thanks in advance.